# Cost per pound savings analysis between two data sets

Tags: statistics

Given 2 sets consisting of (type, cost, weight) and grouping the data into sub-sets based on type (for simplicity let's just say their are two types).

How would you go about comparing these data sets to create a number that represents the cost savings?

### The Dummy Data:

*CPP = Cost Per Pound = Cost/Weight

```
Current Years Data
+-----+------+--------+--------+----------+
|  #  | Type |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
+-----+------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1  | A    | 92.7   | 569    | 0.162917 |
|  2  | A    | 159.14 | 2692   | 0.059115 |
|  3  | B    | 483.65 | 6845   | 0.070657 |
|  4  | B    | 246.06 | 3549   | 0.069332 |
+-----+------+--------+--------+----------+

    Subgroup "Type" = A Totals
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | 251.84 | 3261   | 0.077227 |
    +--------+--------+----------+

    Subgroup "Type" = B Totals
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | 729.71 | 10394  | 0.070205 |
    +--------+--------+----------+

    Grand Totals
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | 981.55 | 13655  | 0.071882 |
    +--------+--------+----------+
```

---

```
Last Years Data
+-----+------+--------+--------+----------+
|  #  | Type |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
+-----+------+--------+--------+----------+
|  1  | A    | 340.78 | 3248   | 0.104919 |
|  2  | A    | 109.13 | 149    | 0.732416 |
|  3  | B    | 199.41 | 755    | 0.264119 |
|  4  | B    | 231.68 | 5416   | 0.042776 |
+-----+------+--------+--------+----------+

    Subgroup "Type" = A Totals
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | 449.91 | 3397   | 0.132296 |
    +--------+--------+----------+

    Subgroup "Type" = B Totals
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | 431.09 | 6171   | 0.069842 |
    +--------+--------+----------+

    Grand Totals
    +--------+--------+----------+
    |  Cost  | Weight |   CPP*   |
    +--------+--------+----------+
    | 881.00 | 9568   | 0.092077 |
    +--------+--------+----------+
```

### My Current (and incorrect) process:

Now my intuition says to calculate savings take the grand total CPP from last year and subtract the grand total CPP from this year.

```
0.092077 - 0.071882 = 0.020195
```

And then multiply that by current years total weight to get:

```
0.020195 * 13655 = 275.76
```

So I would say that their was a $275.76 savings from last year.

---

Now the issue is when you do the same calculations per sub group "Type". I wind up with:

```
Subgroup A Savings:
0.132296 - 0.077227 = 0.055069
0.055069 * 3261 = 179.58
Savings = $179.58

Subgroup B Savings:
0.069842 - 0.070205 = -0.000363
-0.000363 * 10394 = -3.77
Savings = - $3.77

Grand Total Savings:
0.092077 - 0.071882 = 0.020195
0.020195 * 13655 = 275.76
Savings = $275.76
```

**The problem:**

```
$179.58 + (- $3.77) =/= $275.76
```

To reiterate one last time. I am taking the the difference of the cost per pound between two years and then multiplying that by the current months weight. The issue is that the savings per sub group does not equal the overall savings, which is counter intuitive to me, and I must assume I am calculating the savings wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and I apologize for my lack of jargon in the math realm. I'm just looking for a little something to get on the right track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference when you calculate \$179.58 + (- \$3.77) is that you implicitly assume that both types have equal weight, but this is clearly not the case when you look at your subgroup totals in terms of weight. When you compute grand total savings, you do weight according to the total weight of the subtype.

Let's denote costs of an item from last year by $c^0$, and costs of an item from this year by $c^1$; weights are denoted by $w^0$ and $w^1$ respectively. Your grand total CPP is
$$\frac{\sum_Ac^0+\sum_Bc^0}{\sum_Aw^0+\sum_Bw^0}-\frac{\sum_Ac^1+\sum_Bc^1}{\sum_Aw^1+\sum_Bw^1},$$
while your subtype CPP is
$$\frac{\sum_Ac^0}{\sum_Aw^0}-\frac{\sum_Ac^1}{\sum_Aw^1}+\frac{\sum_Bc^0}{\sum_Bw^0}-\frac{\sum_Bc^1}{\sum_Bw^1} $$
which clearly doesn't equal the grand total CPP. In short: yes the results differ, but that's because you calculate two different things.

It seems to me you have to figure out what kind of savings you really want to calculate. Your grand total calculation takes the difference of the cost per pound over all item types, which might be misleading if the majority of items was type A last year but is the minority type this year. In that case it might be better to go with your subtype calculation, which accounts for the fact that the share of the types changes over the years. That is what I would do.

Answer (score 1):

This would probably be better in a comment, but I'm not allowed to comment yet here.

You should decide what you consider "saving". If it's just "how less I spent this year with respect to last year", then why not just subtract the total for this year from the total from last year? In your case it would be $881.00\$ - 981.55\$ = -100.55\$$. This of course does not take into account the fact that you are coping with different quantities over the two years, so while you might have *lost* $100.55\$$ in absolute terms, you might have actually just bought much more stuff and paid a better price for it.

So, type by type, it makes sense to do the comparison, but there is one catch. In each year, you might buy stuff of e.g. type *A* at different unitary costs, so while it makes sense to calculate the average unitary cost of *A* in a year, you cannot just assume that you would have been able to buy additional stuff of type *A* at the same unitary cost. So your question in this case would be like: *what are my savings this year with respect to the last year, assuming that the last year I would have been able to buy this year's amount of stuff of type A at the same unitary price I calculated for last year?*. If you accept this question, then your savings *type by type* will be like what you calculated, although I'd express it differently to indicate the thought process above:

```
Subgroup A Savings:
0.132296 * 3261 - 251.84 = 179.58
Savings = $179.58

Subgroup B Savings:
0.069842 * 10394 - 729.71 = -3.77
Savings = - $3.77
```

Now you have to remember that this is a thought process that has no real counterpart in the reality. As a matter of fact, in the first year you happened to buy *A* twice, and in neither occasion you got the average price you're using in this comparison. So, even at this point your savings calculation is somehow *weak*.

This is important to remember when you try to extend to the *single shot* calculation. Here you are just summing up costs and weights independently of the type. Does this make sense? You only know the answer. If *A* is wheat and *B* is sugar, and you are selling cakes, you can't just trade one for another, so it does not make sense. If *A* is what happened in the first half of the year, and *B* is the second half, but the stuff you're talking about it the same, then the summing up makes sense of course.

Assuming it makes sense, you'll obtain a *saving* for the overall stuff, without regard to the type. It makes perfectly sense that the *saving* in this case is not the same as the plain sum of the two sub-cases, just because you are saying that you're fine with the *super-average* unitary cost as opposed to a unitary cost for each type.

To make you "see" it, would you find it *fair* to calculate the savings considering the first purchase of *A* in the two years, then the savings for the second purchase of *A* in the two years, and so on? I guess not, just because you accept the *illusion* that you did a single purchase of goods of type *A* with a unitary cost that is the weighted average of the costs.